# scenario to use bing speech / custom speech api

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services

Developing a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework and it should have the capability of user can talk in natural language. Currently bot client is in a mobile app and it using the mobile hardware and software to convert the speech to text. Wondering , what will be the use case to use bing speech api ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're working on a platform that has speech-text, but every platform doesn't have that. Companies are increasingly offering smart devices where they might not have their own speech-text conversion, so API is an easy way to get that. Another use case is where a built-in speech-text quality isn't sufficient and the API performs better - it's always good to test to see which is better and what the performance/cost/quality trade-offs are. Another related use case is for special or domain-specific vocabularies where you can train the API to handle your scenario more precisely.

Comment: Thank you. I think the domain specific vocabulary make sense for the scenario im in.